# Ajax request showing error occured:Spring mvc maven project

Tags: java, ajax, maven, spring-mvc

When ajax call happens it shows error occurred without any tomcat error logs. While on browser is displays 400.

Here is my ajax call.

```
    var data = {    
            "topic" : $("#topic").val()}
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "./saveSyllabus",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            alert("Record Added Successfully!!")
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            alert("Error Occured!!")
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
            enableSearchButton(true);
        }
    });
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    UserCreationService userCreationService;

    @Autowired
    SyllabusService syllabusService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/saveSyllabus",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String saveSyllabus(@RequestParam  String topic) {
        System.out.println("in registration controller");

        Integer id= syllabusService.saveSyllabus(syllabusDetails);


        return id;

    }
}
```

I have added required dependancies also:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the controller is configured to response in body, but your are doing a redirect, in your case it seems you want the redirect so remove the **@ResponseBody**:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveSyllabus",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String saveSyllabus(@RequestParam  String topic,RedirectAttributes rd) {
    System.out.println("in registration controller");

    Integer id= syllabusService.saveSyllabus(syllabusDetails);
    if(id>0){
        rd.addFlashAttribute("id", 1);
    } else {
        rd.addFlashAttribute("id",0);
    }

    return "redirect:"+ "/register";

}
```

As your are doing a redirect this sould be a browser URL call and not an Ajax call

Instead if you want to reponse to the body try this

```
var data = {    
        "topic" : $("#topic").val()}
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : "./saveSyllabus",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout : 100000,
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        alert("Record Added Successfully!!")
    },
    error : function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        alert("Error Occured!!")
    },
    done : function(e) {
        console.log("DONE");
        enableSearchButton(true);
    }
});
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveSyllabus",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String saveSyllabus(@RequestBody  String topic) {
    System.out.println("in registration controller");

    Integer id= syllabusService.saveSyllabus(syllabusDetails);

    return String.valueOf(id);

}
```

note **@ReuqestParam** change to **@RequestBody** and the method content changed too

Comment: Done necessary changes still issue persists.Showing required parameter not present 400 on browser.

Comment: the url is something like this _http://<host:port>/<context>/saveSyllabus?topic=exampleTopic_   ??

Comment: Url is localhost:8080/MyProject/saveSyllabus?{"topic":"sdfd"}).Still it shows required param topic is not provided.

Comment: well D: that make no sense, the param is required and you are passing it, its a URL call right?, no ajax?

Comment: It is an ajax call.

Comment: well that is why is failing, if you gonna use ajax, then opt for a no redirect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a String value from @Controller using @ResponseBody but your AJAX is expecting a JSON response from Controller `datatype: 'json',`. Change your AJAX Response expectation to HTML `datatype : 'HTML',` and it will return status 200!